# Identity and Access is Missed in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, sts-securitytokenservice

Need to add STS to my web project, and I got some guide from my colleague:

**Add STS Reference command by right-clicking the web project in Visual Studio and select Identity and Access**

but I can't find it in my VS 2015. Have tried to search it in a google, but failed.
Can somebody tell me, how i can add this service to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-build-claims-aware-aspnet-mvc-web-app-using-wif) Here you can find instruction how to configurate Claims-Based Authentication in you project.