# Identity and Access is Missed in VS 2017

Tags: c#, wcf, wif

I am trying to create a WCF service which uses WIF. Following this [howto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-enable-wif-for-a-wcf-web-service-application) I should right-click the service in Solution Explorer and select **Identity and access**. But I can't find that option in VS 2017.

I have found a solution for ASP.Net MVC applications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593159/identity-and-access-is-missed-in-vs-2015), but I am not sure if that works seamless for WCF services.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the tooling that did this has been deprecated.

As per the article, you can build up the web.config manually. That's probably your best option.

The new way is to use [OWIN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/). I don't know of any OWIN sample for WCF though because the new way of doing this is via web API.

WS-Fed is hardly ever used. The new way is [OIDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).